# Monaca作成したアプリのアップロードができない

Tags: ios, monaca

Monacaで作成したアプリをApplication Loaderでアップロードしようとしていますが

> ERROR ITMS-90055: "This bundle is invalid. The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current value

といったエラーがでてしまいます。調べてみると
http://lifestyleofbakakemu.blogspot.jp/2013/11/iphonethe-bundle-identifier-cannot-be.html
こちらにはBundle IDとSuffixの設定が正しくないとあります。

Bundle IDはProvisioning ProfilesのAPP　IDで
SuffixはMonacaで設定したAPP　IDに設定しています。
他にbundle IDとSuffixの間に .  を入れると解決するというような記事も見ました
しかしMonacaで設定するAPP　IDは . を先頭に入れることができずProvisioning ProfilesのAPP　IDと同じにしないといけないと公式にありました。
どうすれば解決しますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

バンドルIDをあとから生成したものを適用したらできました